# Delegating fragments to children with Relay

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs

I want to do something like this in a component:

```
Relay.createContainer(Component, {
  fragments: {
    thing: AnotherComponent.getFragment('thing')
  }
}
```

This would ideally set the fragment `thing` on my current component to use the fragment `thing` on one of it's child components. Effectively delegating the responsibility of knowing what `thing` is down to whatever uses it. Then the component that includes `Component` can call `Component.getFragment('thing')` which will call `AnotherComponent.getFragment('thing')`.

Does anyone know how to do this?

#### UPDATE

The only way I've found to make this work is via syntax like

```
Relay.createContainer(Component, {
  fragments: {
    thing: Relay.QL`
      ${AnotherComponent.getFragment('thing')}
    `
  }
}
```

This hits the server correctly, and the server executes the query specified by `AnotherComponent`, but now the return value of the query is not provided in the props of `Component`

UPDATE 2

I've found that repeated nesting of this type produces a query like:

```
query Router {

  store {

    ...F3

  }

}
fragment F0 on Store {

  _fields2w4En2:fields(labels:["Country","Function"],owner_type:"requisitions") {

    choices {

      id,

      label

    },

    id
,

    label
  }

}
fragment F1 on Store {

  ...F0

}
fragment F2 on Store {

  ...F1

}
fragment F3 on Store {

  ...F2

}
```

Where at the base level I had a query like this:

```
export default Relay.createContainer(SearchBar, {
  fragments: {
    searchFields: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment searchFields on Store {
        searchFields: fields(labels: ["Country", "Function"], owner_type: "requisitions") {
          label
          choices {
            id
            label
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the reason the straight forward approach doesn't work is becasue `getFragment` doesn't actually return a fragment (ugh), but a reference to a fragment that is specific to the container that declares it. Luckily tho you can get the plain fragment from that, 
with: `AnotherComponent.getFragment('thing').getFragment()`.

see [this playground example](https://facebook.github.io/relay/prototyping/playground.html#source=let%20Nested%20%3D%20(%7B%20greetings%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20%3Ch1%3E%7Bgreetings.hello%7D%3C%2Fh1%3E%3B%0A%7D%20%20%0A%0ANested%20%3D%20Relay.createContainer(Nested%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20fragments%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20greetings%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20fragment%20on%20Greetings%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20hello%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%0Alet%20Example%20%3D%20(props)%20%3D%3E%20%3CNested%20%7B...props%7D%20%2F%3E%0A%0AExample%20%3D%20Relay.createContainer(Example%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20fragments%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20greetings%3A%20(vars)%20%3D%3E%20Nested.getFragment('greetings').getFragment(vars)%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0Aclass%20HelloRoute%20extends%20Relay.Route%20%7B%0A%20%20static%20routeName%20%3D%20'Hello'%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20A%20unique%20name%0A%20%20static%20queries%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20greetings%3A%20(Component)%20%3D%3E%20Relay.QL%60%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20query%20GreetingsQuery%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20greetings%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24%7BComponent.getFragment('greetings')%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%60%2C%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0AReactDOM.render(%0A%20%20%3CRelay.RootContainer%0A%20%20%20%20Component%3D%7BExample%7D%0A%20%20%20%20route%3D%7Bnew%20HelloRoute()%7D%0A%20%20%2F%3E%2C%0A%20%20mountNode%0A)%3B%0A) for a demonstration

Comment: Oh wow. How/where did you even find that? I was looking everywhere. The only problem now is that the fragment queries `fields`, which returns an array. When that gets passed down into the next component, Relay complains that it expected a single record and that the fragment doesn't have @relay(plural: true) on it. The issue is, it shouldn't have plural: true because the array is resolved inside the `fields` query. If it were `{choices {id label} }` then that fragment could have plural, but since `fields` is within the original fragment, it shouldn't need plural: true.

Comment: This all works, but I'm getting this warning for every component that uses it 

`
RelayContainer: component Heade` was rendered with variables that differ from the variables used to fetch fragment store. The fragment was fetched with variables (not fetched), but rendered with variables {}
`

Comment: probably didn't pass through the variables for every fragment...seems unrelated? note that you might need to do `.getFragment('thing', variables).getFragment(variables)`